# Finding peak of an special array with the best order and fastest time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

We have an array A with n elements and We want to find a peak of array B which:

[image]

also:

```
2≤n≤10^6, 1≤Ai≤2×10^9
```

if B has multiple peaks,return one by random.

I tried to solve the problem using divide and conquer method like we do when finding the peak in the array A but I had problems with execution time.
What is the solution?

Comment: Could you give an example? Or maybe rewrite the equation using LaTeX?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I re wrote the equation

Comment: Is that written the right way? You dont even use the variable j. I think an example would help me understand exactly what your question is asking